# Cannot access IIS 7 SMTP Server configuration

Tags: iis-7

hERE
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28WS.10%29.aspx

It is said

> #
>
> Open IIS Manager and navigate to the
>   level you want to manage. For
>   information about opening IIS Manager,
>   see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For
>   information about navigating to
>   locations in the UI, see Navigation in
>   IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>   #
>
> In Features View, double-click SMTP
>   E-mail.

In Features View I see list of features with SMTP Server, but it's just plaintext, no way to double click on it to configure anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the IIS 6 Manager component. That's how I do it in IIS 7.

Comment: Hi I launched IIS6 Manager and the smtp server wasn't running so I started it. But still don't understand why I need to use IIS6 instead of IIS 7 ?

Comment: I don't know that you have to use the IIS6 manager, I just find it easier to configure the SMTP component with it.